# Director.js and Turbolinks - changing the window hash and using then back

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hash, turbolinks

I'm using Director.js in our application along with Turbolinks.

It works perfectly fine when changing the hash, but when using the browser back button (which should just change the hash back to the previous hash, and trigger the relevant Director.js route), Turbolinks takes over and replaces the body causing everything to break. Is there any way to opt out of Turbolinks when changing the window hash with `window.location.hash`?

EDIT: After more Googling, I've found Turbolinks causes issues with other JS routers as well (eg. Backbones's router). I've not found a working solution yet.

My JS looks as follows:

```
var new_item_js = function(){
if (signup_routes_defined == false) {

    var step1 = function() {
        console.log('step one functions go here.');
    };
    var step2 = function() {
        console.log('step two functions go here.');
    };

    var routes = {
        'new_item_step_1': step1,
        'new_item_step_2': step2
    };

    var signup_router = Router(routes);
    signup_router.init();   
    signup_routes_defined = true;

}

$(document).on('page:load ready', new_item_js);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dropping Turbolinks, which is a bummer. Would be great to actually have this working .